# Finding shortest path between two nodes with a set of forbidden nodes

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I have undirected and unweighted graph, in which I would like to find the shortest path between two entered nodes. There is also a set of forbidden nodes. How to find the shortest path, if I am allowed to visit **at most** one node from the set of forbidden nodes?
[image]

Comment: Here is the golden rule of dynamic programming (that is how I can it). If you have an extra condition, then add that condition as a parameter to the subproblem. Given that rule, can you come up with an algorithm?

Comment: cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636459/finding-shortest-path-between-two-nodes-with-a-set-of-forbidden-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer by [hbejgel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3258698/hbejgel) from the StackOverflow:

> 1. Do a BFS starting from END - Whenever it reaches a Forbidden node, update its distance_from_end and don't add its neighbors to your
>      queue. All forbidden nodes that are not visited should not have a
>      valid distance_from_end.
> 2. Do the same as (1) but starting from START and updating distance_from_start
> 3. For all forbidden nodes take the one with minimal distance_from_start + distance_from_end. (note that this node may not
>      exist since nodes can have non valid values in those fields and thus
>      should be disconsidered)
> 4. Do a BFS from start to finish, disconsider all forbidden nodes except the one found in (3).
> 5. From the BFS performed in 4 you'll either:
>
>    - find a path that does not cross any forbidden node which is shorter than the one that would cross it.
>    - find a path that does cross the forbidden node, in this case its length should be equal to (distance_from_start +
>        distance_from_end) for that node.
>    - find no path at all, meaning that you did not find a node in step (3) and that after removing all forbidden nodes from the graph,
>        you get a graph where START and END are in different partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Create two directed copies of the graph, one without the forbidden nodes. Connect the outgoing edges of the "forbidden" nodes to the second graph.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: @Hawklike: I'm not sure what I could be more specific about.  You create a new graph that represents the old graph, using the method above, which can be solved by an off-the-shelf pathfinding algorithm.  This means you don't need to code your own, and can instead use one that's already been optimized and supports a heuristic (A\*).  The other answers do not, despite being more complicated.